# startActivityForResult() is deprecated. Need a solution for my code to understand how the alternative works

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication

I am very much new to Android Studio. I am trying to build an Uber clone using **Java** watching a Youtube tutorial. There is a feature for signing in using Phone number and it has been implemented by using **Firebase Authentication**. In the video, the guy used `startActivityForResult()` but it has been deprecated. **I have looked for the alternatives and found as well. But, it is too tough for me now to understand** how I should change my piece of code. ***Need help !***

Here is my piece of code:

```
package com.example.bustracker;

import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResult;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultCallback;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthMethodPickerLayout;
import com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI;
import com.firebase.ui.auth.IdpResponse;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import io.reactivex.Completable;
import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers;
import io.reactivex.functions.Action;

public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final static int LOGIN_REQUEST_CODE = 4700;
    private List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener listener;


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(listener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        if(firebaseAuth != null && listener != null)
            firebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(listener);
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sign_in_layout);



        init();


    }

    private void init(){
        providers = Arrays.asList(
                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder().build(),
                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build()
        );

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        listener = myFireBaseAuth -> {

            FirebaseUser user = myFireBaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

            if(user != null)
                delaySplashScreen();
            else
                showLoginLayout();
        };
    }

    private void showLoginLayout() {
        AuthMethodPickerLayout authMethodPickerLayout = new AuthMethodPickerLayout
                .Builder(R.layout.sign_in_layout)
                .setPhoneButtonId(R.id.signInButton)
                .setGoogleButtonId(R.id.googleSignInButton)
                .build();

        startActivityForResult(AuthUI.getInstance()
                .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                .setAuthMethodPickerLayout(authMethodPickerLayout)
                .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
                .setTheme(R.style.LoginTheme)
                .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                .build(),LOGIN_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    private void delaySplashScreen() {

        Completable.timer(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(() -> Toast.makeText(SplashScreenActivity.this, "Welcome: "+FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == LOGIN_REQUEST_CODE)
        {
            IdpResponse response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this,"[ERROR]: "+response.getError().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `startActivityForResult` is just deprecated. But you can use it without any issue.

Comment: Please check the duplicate to see how you can solve this. If you understand Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) will also help.